# Inject Specific Type With Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I want to inject specific type when some conditions are met. For example, i have got an interface like below.

```
public interface IMyInterface{

}
```

And also two classes that implement this interface

```
public class MyClassA : IMyInterface {
}
```

and

```
public class MyClassB : IMyInterface {
}
```

Finally i have some service class that gets a constructor parameter as IMyInterface.

```
public class ServiceA{
private IMyInterface _interfaceClass;
public ServiceA(IMyInterface interfaceClass){
_interfaceClass = interfaceClass
}
}
```

and

```
public class ServiceB{
private IMyInterface _interfaceClass;
public ServiceA(IMyInterface interfaceClass){
_interfaceClass = interfaceClass
}
}
```

Now because of some architectural constraints **ServiceA must get MyClassA as constructor parameter** and **ServiceB must get MyClassB as constructor parameter**.

Normally i am using Autofac like below

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyClassA>().As<IMyInterface>().InstancePerApiRequest();
```

But i couldn't find the way how can i force Autofac to select right type for specific type.
I looked to `Named<>` feature but couldn't solve problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Injecting a specific instance of an interface using Autofac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989676/injecting-a-specific-instance-of-an-interface-using-autofac)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have violated Liskov substitution principle

> Now because of some architectural constraints ServiceA must get MyClassA as constructor parameter and ServiceB must get MyClassB as constructor parameter.

I'm not sure that Autofac supports context based injection - why don't you just make each Service dependent on the implementation it requires?

```
public class ServiceA
{
    private IMyInterface _interfaceClass;
    public ServiceA(MyClassA interfaceClass)
    {
        _interfaceClass = interfaceClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you might be right, i didn't try using class type as parameter type. Thanks for answer

Comment: "make each Service dependent on the implementation it requires". That would unfortunately lead to a violation of the Interface Segregation Principle. The problem here is that there is ambiguity in the design. It's better to hide `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` each behind a different abstraction to prevent the ambiguity altogether.

Comment: Autofac supports context based injection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835744/how-to-use-autofac-to-inject-specific-implementation-in-constructor?rq=1