# Autofac registering specific method parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I am using the Autofac IOC with construcor validation. I can't figure out how to register the classes in the IOC so that `LogotypeService` gets `LogoImageValidator` and `AdService` get `AdValidator` injected in it's constructors.

I don't want to specify which instance of SomeClass that should be injected.

I have:

- One validation interface (IImageValidator)
- One base class for the common validation logic (ImageValidatorBase)
- Two subclasses which holds specific valiation logic (LogoImageValidator and AdImageValidator)
- One service interface (IService)
- Two services which each should use different subclasses for validation. (LogotypeService should     use LogoImageValidator) and (AdService should use AdValidator)

**Interface**

```
public interface IImageValidator
{
    bool ValidFileSize();
}
```

**Base class:**

```
public abstract class ImageValidatorBase : IImageValidator
{    
    //constructor omitted
    Public abstract ValidFileSize()
    {
       //shared code
    }
}
```

**Subclass LogoImageValidator**

```
public class LogoImageValidator : ImageValidator
{
    //constructor omitted
    public override bool ValidFileSize()
    {
        //class specific code
    }
}
```

**Subclass AdImageValidator**

```
public class AdImageValidator : ImageValidator
{
    //constructor omitted
    public override bool ValidFileSize()
    {
        //class specific code
    }
}
```

**IService**

```
public interface IService{
    bool ValidFileSize();
}
```

**LogotypeService**

```
 public class LogotypeService : IService
 {
    private readonly ISomeClass _someClass;
    private readonly IImageValidator _imageValidator;

    public LogotypeService(ISomeClass someClass, IImageValidator imageValidator)
    {
        _someClass = someClass;
        _imageValidator = imageValidator;
    }

    public bool ValidFileSize()
    {
       _imageValidator.ValidFileSize();//use LogoImageValidator subclass here            
    }
}
```

**AdService**

```
 public class AdService : IService
 {
    private readonly ISomeClass _someClass;
    private readonly IImageValidator _imageValidator;

    public AdService(ISomeClass someClass, IImageValidator imageValidator)
    {
        _someClass = someClass;
        _imageValidator = imageValidator;
    }

    public bool ValidFileSize()
    {
       _imageValidator.ValidFileSize();//use AdValidator subclass here    
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What methods does your `IService` interface has?

Comment: Hi, I added the IService in my latest edit. It exposes: bool ValidFileSize()

Comment: This is somewhat overlapping with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699588/inject-specific-type-with-autofac

Comment: Hi @TravisIllig. Your link actually solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so folks know the question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to overlap with this question: [Inject Specific Type With Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699588/inject-specific-type-with-autofac)

The answer there suggests that different interfaces be used based on context.