# How to use Autofac to inject specific implementation in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have two classes that take a `ILastActivityUpdator` as a constructor parameter: `UserService` and `AnonymousUserService`.

```
public AnonymousUserService(ILastActivityUpdator lastActivityUpdator)
{
    if (lastActivityUpdator == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("lastActivityUpdator");
    }
    this.lastActivityUpdator = lastActivityUpdator;
}
```

And similar as above for `UserService`:

```
public UserService(ILastActivityUpdator lastActivityUpdator)
{
    if (lastActivityUpdator == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("lastActivityUpdator");
    }
    this.lastActivityUpdator = lastActivityUpdator;
}
```

`ILastActivityUpdator` interface has one method: `UpdateLastActivity(int userId)`. There are two implementations of the interface, a `LastActivityUpdator` and a decorator called `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` which inherits from `LastActivityUpdator` and adds some extra functionality to the method, like so:

```
public class AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator 
    : LastActivityUpdator, IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator
{
    public AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator()
    { }

    public override void UpdateLastActivity(int userId)
    {
        base.UpdateLastActivity(userId);

        // Extra functionality
    }
}
```

I now want use Autofac to wire up the `AnonymousUserService` with the `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` and the `UserService` with the `LastActivityUpdator`.

What I tried is to add an interface for the decorator that derives from the base interface like so:

```
public interface IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator : ILastActivityUpdator
{ }
```

Then I thought I could use the `IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` in the `AnonymousUserService` constructor and everything would be autowired properly.

Unfortunately it just always uses the first implementation, being `IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` since it is registered earlier (alphabetical order).

How can I accomplish that the `AnonymousUserService` gets the `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` injected and the `UserService` the `LastActivityUpdator`?

Comment: [This question is actually an FAQ on the Autofac doc site.](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Autofac is [nicely documented](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/index.html) and it looks like you can find what you are after [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html#passing-parameters-to-register). From what I can tell, if you have registered your updators with

```
builder.RegisterType<LastActivityUpdator>();
builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>();
```

then you should be able to register your services with

```
builder.Register(c => new UserService(c.Resolve<LastActivityUpdator>()));
builder.Register(c => new AnonymousUserService(c.Resolve<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()));
```

or

```
builder.RegisterType<UserService>().WithParameter(
    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILastActivityUpdator),
    (p, c) => c.Resolve<LastActivityUpdator>());

builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserService>().WithParameter(
    (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILastActivityUpdator),
    (p, c) => c.Resolve<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>());
```

Then when you resolve `UserService` or `AnonymousUserService` from the container, they will get the correct dependencies.

As an aside, if an interface is injected into a class, then that class should function correctly with all implementations of that interface ([LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). From the class names, it looks like `AnonymousUserService` only works with `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` and not any implementation of `ILastActivityUpdator`. If that is the case, then it might be appropriate to introduce a different abstraction (like `IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator`) as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks a lot. It only functions with a `IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` so you are right that it should depend on that. I think my mistake was letting the `IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` derive from `ILastActivityUpdator`, therefore the first matching was selected. I will try not letting it inherit this evening. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds correct however you shouldn't change you design based on your IoC. If it makes sense for `IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` to inherit from `ILastActivityUpdator` then it should, and you can set up your bindings as above. Good luck with it :)

Comment: the `builder.Register(c => new UserService(c => c.Resolve<LastActivityUpdator>()));` syntax is not correct. "A local variable named c cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to c, which is already used in `parent or current' scope to denote something else.

Comment: There shouldn't have been a second lambda. I've corrected it

Comment: Matt, I tried implementing your suggestion after refactoring to a decorator pattern, and I always get the `AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator` injected, even when I want it to be a `LastActivityUpdator`. Maybe you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926589/how-to-use-autofac-to-inject-decorator-in-one-constructor-and-decorated-class-in. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be working for me. I've put together a quick [example](https://gist.github.com/mattwcole/65a8d5a1adb8179932ba)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the previous response, in this case you're breaking the Liskov principle. In fact, your consumer classes depend on diferent interfaces implementations. Even if the interface are excatly the same one, the functionality it's not. And you need to reflect that:

1. in each consumer class, depend on the right interface
2. register each implementation as the appropriate interface

That you can derive one implementation from the other is completely irrelevant from the DI point of view: it doesn't matter if the implementations are the same class, or are completely independent, or one derives from the other, as in this case.

For more details, check [Autofac's Services vs Components](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#services-vs-components) docs. You'll see that all the above options are possible.

Taking this into account:

1. In each consumer class constructor, specify the right interface dependency:

```
    public AnonymousUserService(IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator lastActivityUpdator)
    public UserService(ILastActivityUpdator lastActivityUpdator)
```

2. And register each implementation as the right interface:

```
    builder.RegisterType<LastActivityUpdator>()
      .As<ILastActivityUpdator>();
    builder.RegisterType<AnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>()
      .As<IAnonymousUserLastActivityUpdator>;
```

In this way, each consumer class will automatically get injected the right implementation.