# Constructor injection multiple implementations in Unity Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

For the following interfaces and classes, how do I use Unity Container to Fluently (programatically) wire it up so that `FooController` gets an instance of `ARepository` and `BarController` gets an instance of `BRepository` via constructor injection?

```
public interface IRepository
{
}

public class ARepository : IRepository
{
}

public class BRepository : ARepository
{
}

public class FooController
{
    public FooController(IService service, IRepository repository)
    {
    }
}

public class BarController
{
    public BarController(IService service, IRepository repository)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The dup question looks different, but the answer is exactly the same.

Comment: Here is another one where the answer works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989676/injecting-a-specific-instance-of-an-interface-using-autofac

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this at registration time by telling each controller registration how to resolve its constructor parameters.

```
container.RegisterType<FooController>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedParameter<IService>(), new ResolvedParameter<ARepository>());

container.RegisterType<BarController>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedParameter<IService>(), new ResolvedParameter<BRepository>());
```

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend against creating a dedicated/local/injected UnityContainer for each type like one of the posters suggested.

This can be approached in two ways.

One is by specifically defining the resolving in registration time as *TylerOhlsen* suggested.
This is a good solution, though if you register later both *ARepository* and *BRepository* as implementations for *IRepository*, you still need to deal with the fact you have two implenetations for the same interface, and if a third class will someday require an implementation of *IRepository*, without defining it specifically in the registration, it will get an unpredictable instance.

The second option, which is slightly safer, is registering a factory for *IRepository*.
The simplest example would be using a string as the key, like this:

```
// Create a resolver(abstract factory) for the IRepository interface type
var resolver = myContainer.Resolve<Func<IRepository>>();

// ... other code here...

// Register mappings for the IRepository interface to appropriate concrete types
myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, ARepository>("A");
myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, BRepository>("B");
```

Then in the implementation of FooController and BarController receive the func factory by injection and select the right instance.

```
public class FooController
{
   IRepository repository;

   public FooController(IService service, Func<IRepository> repositoryFactory)
   {
       repository = repositoryFactory("A");
   }
}
```

You can read more about this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660854%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can register the type with a name and then use that in a `Dependency` attribute of the target classes:

```
// Register mappings for the IRepository interface to appropriate concrete types
myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, ARepository>("A");
myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, BRepository>("B");
```

Then in the FooController and BarController, declare which implementation you require with the Dependency attribute:

```
public class FooController
{
    public FooController(IService service, [Dependency("A")] IRepository repository)
    {
    }
}

public class BarController
{
    public BarController(IService service, [Dependency("B")] IRepository repository)
    {
    }
}
```

You can use a `public const string` in `ARepository` and `BRepository` rather than `"A"` and `"B"` in both `RegisterType` and `Dependency`.

Comment: doesn't it defeat the whole purpose of using dependency  injection if we state the dependency on class rather than a confirgurator or something?

Comment: The class is stating that it needs a particular "flavour" of IService but the actual IService type which is instantiated is resolved at runtime and dependant on how the types are registered.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to register the specific type to be resolved by the `UnityContainer` when resolving `IRepository`:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRepository, BRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Using this depends on whether you require finer grained control over what types are resolved in certain contexts - if you do, you might consider using a local `IUnityContainer` instance and using `RegisterInstance()` instead:

```
//Assumes container is instantiated and already populated with other instances/type mappings.
IUnityContainer childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
container.RegisterInstance<IRepository>(new BRepository(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Answer (score 1):

*JoefGoldstein* got me most of the way, but I got a few errors when attempting that.

I had to register my classes with a named dependency and use the InjectionFactory class to resolve the dependency.

```
// register interfaces to implementations with a named dependency 
myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, ARepository>("A");
myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, BRepository>("B");

// register Injection factory to resolve the dependency
container.RegisterType<Func<string, IRepository>>(
            new InjectionFactory(c =>
            new Func<string, IRepository>(name => c.Resolve<IRepository>(name)))
);
```

Then in my controller

```
public class FooController
{
   IRepository repository;

   public FooController(IService service, Func<string, IRepository> repositoryFactory)
   {
       repository = repositoryFactory("A");
   }
}
```